# LuaLaTeX finds system font but does not use it

Tags: luatex, fontspec

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}

Libertinus Math:
\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}
\begin{equation}
  x
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

I'm using the 2017 pretest, which has `libertinus` installed as a CTAN package.
However, I also have an updated version of the font in my `.fonts` directory.

`luaotfload-tool` finds it:

```
$ luaotfload-tool --find=libertinusmath --fuzzy
luaotfload | resolve : Font "libertinusmath" found!
luaotfload | resolve : Resolved file name "/home/amalia/.fonts/Libertinus/libertinusmath-regular.otf"
```

but `fontspec` does not use it:

```
</home/amalia/tlpretest/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/libertinus/lib
ertinusmath-regular.otf></home/amalia/tlpretest/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/publi
c/libertinus/libertinusmath-regular.otf></home/amalia/tlpretest/texmf-dist/font
s/opentype/public/lm/lmroman10-regular.otf>
Output written on test.pdf (1 page, 12168 bytes).
Transcript written on test.log.
```

If I've not updated the DB using `--prefer-texmf`,  then why does LuaLaTeX use the TEXMF version?

Comment: your log shows the font is used `.... libertinusmath-regular.otf`

Comment: I know, but if you see its path, it's not the one from `.fonts`.

Comment: oh if you have two files of the same name in your input path it's pretty much a black art which gets loaded luatex(or rather luaotfload) will use its cached luc file so regenerating that might work but I'd remove one of them. If that's the issue I'l delete my answer:-)